# How to implement click event using button which is declared with LiteralControl in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have create design with aspx.cs page in asp.net. I want to implement button for each row and its displaying, but click event was not occurred. There is the following code:

```
Panel4.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td bgcolor=#E0E0E0><strong style='padding-left:10px;'><asp:Button ID='btnEdit' runat='server' onClick='btnEdit_Click' Text='Edit' class='btn btn-primary' />Edit</strong></td>"));
```

What can I do for click event?

Comment: Can you provide little more details as your way of implementation is seems incorrect.

Comment: You cannot create an ASPNET button control as a string and expect it to work. You need to add actual Dynamic Controls to the page.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET doesn't convert server button syntax to a valid html button in that way

Here's an alternative

```
HtmlTableCell tdControl = new HtmlTableCell();
HtmlGenericControl strongControl = new HtmlGenericControl("strong");
Button  btnEdit = new Button();            
btnEdit.Click+=new EventHandler(btnEdit_Click);
btnEdit.Attributes["class"] = "btn btn-primary";
btnEdit.Text = "Edit";
Panel4.Controls.Add(tdControl);
tdControl.Controls.Add(strongControl);
strongControl.Controls.Add(btnEdit);
```